# dotnet core generate migration script with data seed

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm in .Net Core 3.1 C#.
I would like to deploy my application to a IIS test server, I can't use CLI on this server so I generated my SQL script with this command :
`dotnet ef migrations script`

The produced SQL file contains only the database schema, not any seed data, despite in local when I run the commande
`Update-Database`
My database is initialized with seed data...

How to generate SQL script with seed data ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which problems do you have with this documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding

Comment: If I follow your link, there is no command line to generate an SQL file with seed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching on internet, I found the last command I looking for :

```
  Add-Migration SeedInitialData
  Update-Database
  Script-Migration
```

Last command will generate the needed SQL file.